# Adding page in SimpleCMSBundle programmatically

Tags: symfony, symfony-cmf

I am looking for a way to add pages programmatically in SimpleCMSBundle. I found the following  command line.

```
php app/console doctrine:phpcr:migrator page --identifier=/cms/simple/test
```

What I need is first a programmatic equivalent for the above command, secondly the above command assumes that there exists a .yml file located at 'app/Resources/data/
pages/test.yml, I want to provide this information programmatically too.

I am using Symfony CMF Standard edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SimpleCmsBundle provides 2 ways of creating pages:

#### 1. Creating a yaml file which will be parsed

This is done by a DataFixture. The AcmeDemoBundle comes with such a yaml file, which you can use to add your own page:

```yaml
# src/Acme/MainBundle/Resources/data/page.yml
static:
    # ...

    my_new_page:
        name: "my_page"
        label: "My Page"
        title: "My new Page"
        body: "I've added this when following instructions on SO"
```

Now you need to execute `php app/console doctrine:phpcr:fixtures:load`, which will execute the DataFixtures, and the new page is created!

#### 2. Persisting the documents

What's really done with the yaml data is that a `Page` document is created and persisted in the PHPCR tree. Inside a DataFixture, or in a controller/admin where you want to add a page, do the following:

```php
use Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\SimpleCmsBundle\Doctrine\Phpcr\Page;

// ...
$page = new Page();
$page->setName('my_other_page');
$page->setLabel('My other Page');
$page->setTitle('My other Page');
$page->setBody('I\'ve added this myself!!');

$documentManager = ...; // get the document manager, the first argument of DataFixture::load or $container->get('doctrine_phpcr')->getManager()

$root = $documentManager->find(null, '/cms/simple'); // get the root document
$page->setParent($root); // add document to the root

$documentManager->persist($page); // add the page in the queue for persisting
$documentManager->flush(); // execute the queries
```

For more information: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/book/database_layer.html